# Kaltura Install on Plesk / Media Temple DV3.5 apachectl error

Tags: php, apache, subdomain, plesk, mediatemple

Some pain today as with everything new and exciting.  I am attempting to install Kaltura CE on a subdomain on my Media Temple DV runnning plesk 8.6.0.  I get to a step that asks for my `apachectl` path and I enter correctly but keep getting errors as listed below.  I do know this is meant to be on a dedicated box but as with everything I am sure there is a way to make it work.

```
> /usr/sbin/apachectl

The path you inserted is not valid. Please try again.
The full pathname to your Apache apachectl/apache2ctl file:
Examples:
/usr/bin/apachectl
/usr/bin/apache2ctl
/opt/lampp/bin/apachectl
sh: /which: No such file or directory
sh: /which: No such file or directory
>
```

As always,  any and all help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much pain and hours of trying to make something work that really cannot work.  I set up a [linode.com](http://linode.com) box using Ubuntu 10.0.4 and installed kaltura following the directions from kaltura.org. Getting this to work would involve modifying your `my.conf` file to support `lower_case_table_names = 1` which will render Plesk unusable.  My recommendations for installing Kaltura would be to follow the step by step instructions using the patched xampp file they provide you with.

[Installing Kaltura on 10.04](http://www.kaltura.org/kaltura-ce-setting-prerequisites-ubuntu-1004-wxampp)